# Regex for FQDNs works in Python but not with MySQL's RLIKE operator

Tags: python, mysql, regex, mysql-5.6, rlike

I would like help formulating a regex which I can query MySQL5.6 with to get a list of hostnames which are in proper FQDN format.

I found the following regex doing an online search which closely matches what I'm looking for https://www.regextester.com/98986
`"^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){2,}([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2,}$"`

When I tested this regex in python, it gave me the results I expected.

```
>>> reg = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){2,}([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2,}$"
>>> hostname ='abc.tmp.company.com'
>>> print(re.search(reg,hostname))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x109da5880>
>>> res = re.search(reg,hostname)
>>> res.group(0)
'abc.tmp.company.com'
>>> invalid_hostname ='invalid'
>>> print(re.search(reg,invalid_hostname))
None
>>> invalid_hostname2 = 'in-test-stg'
>>> print(re.search(reg,invalid_hostname2))
None
```

But when I queried MySQL, it returned names which were in non-FQDN format too i.e. single word names such as 'invalid' were returned from the DB.

```
select name from MYTABLE 
where name RLIKE '^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.){2,}([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2,}$'
```

I've reviewed https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/ but there might be something I'm missing.

How can I get that regular expression to work in MYSQL with the RLIKE operator? Alternatively, what regular expression can I use when querying MYSQL natively to return names which are in FQDN form?

Comment: You need to double the backslashes in SQL strings.

Comment: It also may not allow escaping `-` inside character sets. You don't need to escape it if it's the first or last character.

Comment: Great, thanks @Barmar I added the extra backslash and now I'm closer to what I'm looking for! ``` "^(([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\\.){2,}([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]){2,}$" ``` Now we get FQDN-like results. The final step is that I need to update the regex not to give me results matching IP Addresses, i.e. all digits so I'm working through that exercise now as well. If anyone has any pointers as I'm working on that, it would help.

Comment: Can't use `{,2}` before version 8.0.

Comment: And the 8.0 documentation doesn't actually mention that it's allowed. You can write `{2,}` in either version.